# PouchDB take array values

Tags: javascript, react-native, pouchdb

I have a problem with PouchDB with array values.

In my document on the DB I have:

```
"ExercisesData": [
        {
          "Id": "01",
          "Reps": "10",
          "StartDate": "2019-06-20",
          "EndDate": "2019-06-21",
          "Notes": ".........."
        },
        {
          "Id": "02",
          "Reps": "1",
          "Notes": "........"
        },
        {
          "Id": "03",
          "Reps": "150",
          "Notes": "........"
        }
  ]
```

I need to print this values, and let choose one of these values (Id) at the user.

I've tried to take this values from the db in this way:

```
findUtente(cf) {
        let params = {};
        params = {
          "Person.FiscalCode": cf
        };
        global.utente.db.localdb().find({
          selector: {params},
        })
          .then(response => {
              let utente = response.docs[0];
              console.log(utente);
              this.setState({ Id: utente.ExercisesData.Id })
              console.log("utente.ExercisesData.Id: " + utente.ExercisesData.Id)

            })
            .catch(function(err) {
              console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
            });
          } 
          render() {
            console.log("this.state.Id: " + this.state.Id)
            return(
                <View>
                    <Text>{this.state.Id}</Text>
                </View>
            );
          }
```

But this code go in the catch, give me back the error: {}
The problem should be that I'm trying to take the elements in wrong way. Maybe I should use the .Map param ?
How can I do to recover these value and print them in a page? Thank you.

Comment: No one can help me??

Answer (score 0):

I have solved in this way:

```
 const exercises = this.state.Exercises.map(exercise => {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 15 }}> {exercise.Id}</Text>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 15 }}> {exercise.Reps}</Text>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 15 }}> {exercise.Notes}</Text>
```